# data not spliced in the following code

Tags: jquery

```
    formData=$("form").serializeArray();


    for(var i=0; i<formData.length;i++){
        console.log(i+': '+formData[i].name+': ' +formData[i].value);
        if(formData[i].value=="") {
            formData.splice(i,1);
            console.log(i);
        } 

    }
```

I have a serialized array of data and I want to remove the empty object the array as indicated in the code above. I am not sure why splice is not doing the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I realize why this didn't splice correctly. The reason is that the length of array decreases after the splice happens, and the `i` stays the same.. To fix this, I did the following:

```
formData=$("form").serializeArray();
l = formData.length;

        for(var i=0; i<l;i++){
            console.log(i+': '+formData[i].name+': ' +formData[i].value);
            if(formData[i].value=="") {
                formData.splice(i,1);
                l--; //reset length of array 
                i--; //reset i 
            }           
        }
```